# Is it $L^2$ function ?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

For $f ∈ L^2
([0, 1))$, define $Vf(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(t) dt$.
Is $Vf$ continuous function?
Is it in $L^2$?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please add your thoughts. Do you see why if the answer to the first question is yes, then you can answer the second question?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes to both questions: Let $x,y\in [0,1)$ such that $y<x$. Then
$$
|Vf(x)-Vf(y)|=|\int_y^xf(t)dt|\leq\int_y^x|f(t)|dt=\int_0^1|f(t)|\chi_{[y,x]}(t)dt\leq ||f||_2|x-y|^{1/2}
$$
where in the last inequality we use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. So $Vf$ is continuous. On the other hand,  by the previous step
$$
\int_0^1|\int_0^xf(t)dt|^2dx\leq\int_0^1||f||_2^2xdx=\frac{||f||_2^2}{2}
$$
So $Vf$ is in $L^2[0,1)$.